# How to access shell script variable as groovy variable in Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: python, shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have generated the output of SGID value set in shell script from sh""" """ via terraform but i want to get the shell variable and again outside in groovy steps but I'm getting following error.  Thanks in advance

```
  stages {
    stage('test') {
      steps {
        script {
              try {
                sh '''
                    cd SG
                    export TF_VAR_aws_vpc_id="${vpc_id}"
                    export TF_VAR_SysName="${sysname}"
                    export TF_VAR_name="${name}"
                    export TF_VAR_Env="${environment}"
                    export TF_VAR_TSM="${TSM}"
                    export TF_VAR_SysOwner="${Sysowner}"
                    export TF_VAR_RequestItem="${RITM}"
                    export TF_VAR_CostCenter="${cc}"
                    export TF_VAR_BusinessUnit="${bu}"
                    export TF_VAR_Department="${dept}"
                    terraform init -no-color
                    terraform validate -no-color
                    terraform plan -no-color
                    terraform apply -auto-approve 
                    terraform output 
                    export SGID=$(terraform output)
                    echo $SGID
                '''
              } catch (err) {
                    echo "Caught: ${err}"
                    sh '''
                        cd SG
                        terraform destroy -auto-approve
                        echo "Terraform destroyed"  
                    '''
                    currentBuild.result = 'Failure'
                    echo "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"
                }       
            })
        }}}
    }
        post {
        success{ script {
            result = sh (   
                script: "python snow-api.py '${SGID} has provisioned on params.Account at ${timestamp}'",   
                returnStdout: true
            ).trim()            
        }}
    }
}
```

Output is :

```
Error when executing success post condition:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: SGID for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:271)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:353)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in the way you are trying. As a workaround, you can do something like the one below.

```
stages {
    stage('test') {
      steps {
        script {
              try {
                sh '''
                    cd SG
                    export TF_VAR_aws_vpc_id="${vpc_id}"
                    export TF_VAR_SysName="${sysname}"
                    export TF_VAR_name="${name}"
                    export TF_VAR_Env="${environment}"
                    export TF_VAR_TSM="${TSM}"
                    export TF_VAR_SysOwner="${Sysowner}"
                    export TF_VAR_RequestItem="${RITM}"
                    export TF_VAR_CostCenter="${cc}"
                    export TF_VAR_BusinessUnit="${bu}"
                    export TF_VAR_Department="${dept}"
                    terraform init -no-color
                    terraform validate -no-color
                    terraform plan -no-color
                    terraform apply -auto-approve 
                    terraform output 
                    export SGID=$(terraform output)
                    echo $SGID >> SGID_OUT
                '''
              } catch (err) {
                    echo "Caught: ${err}"
                    sh '''
                        cd SG
                        terraform destroy -auto-approve
                        echo "Terraform destroyed"  
                    '''
                    currentBuild.result = 'Failure'
                    echo "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"
                }       
            })
        }}}
    }
        post {
        success{ script {
            result = sh (   
                script: "SGID=\$(cat SGID_OUT); python snow-api.py ${SGID} 'has provisioned on params.Account at ${timestamp}'",   
                returnStdout: true
            ).trim()            
        }}
    }
}
```

Here I"m writing the SGID to a file and reading it in the post step.

Answer (score 0):

You could capture sh output like so:

```
env.SGID = sh (script: '''
                    echo $SGID
                    ''', returnStdout: true)
```

and then refer it in post section:

```
python snow-api.py ${env.SGID}
```

2 things to remember:

- all sh output will be caught (I do not know if terraform commands produce any)
- env.SGID will contain String value so you need to cast it to other type in case you need to refer to non-string